# Why do some columns contain blank values when I run a Custom SQL query in Tableau Prep and how can I retrieve the correct (non-empty) values?

Tags: mysql, encryption, aes, data-visualization, tableau-api

Some background...We are trying to connect to a MySQL database and extract patient information. In Tableau Prep, we connect successfully to the database, then create a Custom SQL input. The custom query selects values from a column in a table containing encrypted data. Normally when pulling this data in other situations (such as in our backend code), we decrypt it as part of the SELECT query using AES_DECRYPT. That query usually looks like the following (sometimes there will be more fields than this but they will all follow the same general pattern):

```
SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(UNHEX(`myfield`), 'ThisIsWhereTheKeyWouldGo') AS CHAR) AS myfield FROM `mytable`
```

These names and any values below are just examples by the way...I'm unable to share actual data or names for privacy reasons. 
That being said, when I run this query in MySQL workbench, the result is the column of non-empty-string, non-null values I expect (except of course if the value is actually null to begin with). That's true for any column I run it on that contains encrypted values, regardless of the length of the encrypted string. I.e. the result looks something like....

```
+-----------------------------------+
|             myfield               |
+-----------------------------------+
| somedata                          |
| alsodata                          |
| moredata                          |
| ...etc.                           |
+-----------------------------------+
```

However, when I copy the EXACT SAME query and paste it into Tableau's custom SQL window, then run it, I am getting back empty string values (not null values, but blank ones....And Tableau does differentiate between them). Not an error in sight. This is true for almost every column in my table. Basically I get

```
+-----------------------------------+
|             myfield               |
+-----------------------------------+
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
|                                   |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Notice I said almost every, however. That's because there ARE columns in the SAME EXACT TABLE I run this query on in Tableau and obtain the non-null, non-empty-string results I'm expecting.

That's very puzzling to me. I am struggling to wrap my head around why Tableau can retrieve some columns without issue and not others without them being empty strings.

I'm also struggling to understand whether this is a limitation of our database itself, or if Tableau has a bug.

I also did some cross checking and a cursory glance tells me that ONLY values that were originally non-null in the original data are appearing as empty strings in Tableau's results. The only null values in Tableau's results come from values that were originally null anyway in the original data.

I also tested to see whether the length of the string makes a difference (the values that are coming back as empty strings are somewhat long in the original database and I suspected they might have been truncated before decryption). I copied data from one of the columns where all values are retrieved by my query successfully (are not empty strings) and placed it into a column that normally comes back as empty strings. That data STILL came back as empty strings.

So then should I assume the problem is with the column?  Beyond the above, the ONLY difference in the columns that decrypt correctly and the columns that don't is the type. The columns that decrypt correctly are varchar and the ones that don't are longtext.

At the moment, it isn't feasible for me (and I don't think I have privileges actually....) to modify the data type of the problematic columns and see if that's the issue. I attempted to do this on my local machine/local database copy of course, but unfortunately some searching and attempts reveal that it's only possible for Tableau Prep to connect to my local MySQL database with Tableau Bridge, which is only available for Windows. My workstation unfortunately is a Macbook.

I still find it odd that the query works consistently in MySQL workbench but not Tableau Prep.

So I'm wondering if anyone else has had a problem like this and what you did to work around it. I find it extremely hard to believe I'm the only one in the world who has ever had issues connecting Tableau to a MySQL database and retrieving encrypted data. I would be very surprised if the only workaround for this is changing our entire database to avoid a certain datatype, and am posting here at least partially to see if there are other things that I can try or check that I'm not aware of, and only recommend we create a new table or change datatypes in the current one as an absolute last resort.

I'm also open to solutions that involve Tableau Desktop rather than Tableau Prep. It'll be a bit of a pain but I'll manage.

I'm also wondering if there is an alternative to the Tableau Prep custom query option, such as some built-in equivalent of the AES_DECRYPT function that isn't well-known enough to show up in any of my google or forum searches...Something I can use to decrypt AFTER pulling in the data. Because pulling in the data WITHOUT attempting to decrypt it works fine. E.G.

```
SELECT `myfield` FROM `mytable`
```

Will return non-empty strings as expected in Tableau, they're just still encrypted obviously.

(And before anyone says it because I've seen how asking things goes for people on here half the time.

- I don't control our choices of OS, database, etc. I'm just a lowly dev. I wear a lot of hats yes but I don't have most of the final say in things.
- Storing an unencrypted copy of this data is not an option and is a legal liability for us.
- Yes. Yes I did google and search forums for days. I have to be ABSOLUTELY desperate to post here. This place terrifies me. In fact I don't think I actually have.)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: If anyone needs to know I'm using Tableau Prep Builder 2020.1

Comment: We don't need to see real data. But we do need to see a real demonstration

Comment: As a test, I would do a simple connection in Tableau desktop using custom SQL and examine the SQL that Tableau generates. You can either do this by looking at the log in your repository directory, best with the log viewer tool from github - or even easier by making a performance recording (under the Help menu) For the test, you might want to turn off Aggregation from the Analysis menu

Comment: Please keep us updated

Comment: You could also try opening a support ticket with Tableau via their web site

Comment: @AlexBlakemore I didn't know I could actually examine that. I will try to do that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @psyence Two tips for getting SQL from a Performance Recording. 1. If the query returns quickly, you may need to adjust the slider filter to see the query at all (by default it  is set to not display very quick actions) and 2. When you click on a query, you’ll see the SQL below but it will be truncated in the dashboard view. To see the complete SQL query, select the query and copy data into a text editor. See the Worksheet menu to find the appropriate copy command. When you paste, you should see the full query. again, in this specific case, consider turning off aggregation for testing.